# Cannot reach Spark Web UI located inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, apache-spark, centos7, rhel7

I have a remote Virtual Machine and I'm developing a Spark Application that runs inside a Docker container.

```
2018-12-16 13:07:10 INFO  main [AbstractConnector] - Started ServerConnector@79c3f01f{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
2018-12-16 13:07:10 INFO  main [Utils] - Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
...
2018-12-16 13:07:10 INFO  main [SparkUI] - Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://f58300e7e6ea:4040
```

The log says that it launched SparkUI correctly, but binded to the container's localhost. At this point i decided to `EXPOSE` port 4040 during the building phase and to publish it during `run` with `-p 4040:4040/tcp` binding the two ports.

When i try to reach `<remote host name>:4040` from my local machine (in Firefox) i can't connect to SparkUI. I also tried to telnet it but nothing.

When i start the container i can see the 4040 port listeining using `netstat` but maybe it is not reachable from remote. How can i manage to do this?

Basically I want to reach SparkUI from my Home PC --> Remote VM --> (Docker Container with Spark UI) using my browser.

The Remote VM runs RHEL 7.

Comment: Can the spark UI be accessed from inside Remote VM ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @HansikaMadushanWeerasena. Well, i tried `nc localhost 4040` on the VM and... i don't get any answer! How could this be possible?

Comment: What is your spark master ? is it local?

Comment: @HansikaMadushanWeerasena yes, it is local.

Comment: @L.Don, did you ever resolve this?  I'm having the same issue.  It claims to have started, but there is nothing running on 4040 in that docker container.

Answer (score 4):

The below command worked for me for pyspark

```
docker run -p 4040:4040 --hostname localhost -it apache/spark-py /opt/spark/bin/pyspark
```

Answer (score 3):

In your logs it says that spark UI is started at `started at http://f58300e7e6ea:4040` in here `f58300e7e6ea` is a docker internal network hostname.

So what you have to do is following,

First in your application before deployment set following two configs

1. `spark.driver.bindAddress` as the hostname of any string of your choise
2. `spark.driver.host` as your Remote VM ip address.

Secondly when you are deploying the docker container using image use `--hostname` flag to introduce a hostname to the container and use the previously selected string. As example `docker run --hostname myHostName --ip 10.1.2.3 ubuntu:16.04`

Comment: So let's say that the *container* sees the host machine on private ip _H_.Should set `spark.driver.host=H` and `spark.driver.bindAddress=fooHostname`. Doing that `run ... --hostname fooHostname -p 4040:4040/tcp ..`?

Comment: If your spark master is type local then this answer is not suitable. Then this should work if your 4040 port is mapped to docker container port. Do a docker ps on Remote Host and make sure that port is mapped correctly.